# Error when trying to create a table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

When I use this code

```
CREATE TABLE $this->session->userdata('receiver_db').$receiver_table LIKE $this->session->userdata('sender_db').$sender_table
```

I get this message:

> Object of class CI_Sessin could not be converted to string

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata('receiver_db')); // Returns string(14) "webprog24_reza"
var_dump($receiver_table); // Returns string(9) "guestbook"
```

Why am I getting this error? I am trying to copy a table from one database to another.

Comment: Usually the userdata returns an objects besides of a string.

Comment: @AliSajid thank you, this helped me. I have added an answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the sessions as variables, helped me solve this problems:

```
$db1 = $this->session->userdata('receiver_db');
$db2 = $this->session->userdata('sender_db');
$this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver')->query("CREATE TABLE $db1.$receiver_table LIKE $db2.$sender_table");
```